# Consecutive day count with total

Tags: sql-server

Is there a way to show if the days go consecutively? I need to show a total for when the date is 5 consecutive.

The data is shown below. Could I put a date range for April like: date between 2019-04-01 and 2019-05-31 and show the DATEPART(WEEK,date) for the first date of the 5 consecutive.

I'd like to show the total of 5 consecutive days like below. It skips the week that did not have a date for 5 consecutively.

```
Week Total
21    7.50
23    7.50
```

[image]

Comment: Just like your other question....you need to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Could you explain your question in more detail?
Like what you are getting and what exactly you want

Comment: right now I am getting just the total for the week by using DATEPART(WEEK,date)  but it doesn't limit the weeks if there isn't 5 dates in a row so it shows every week. I'd like exactly how it is shown with the week and total above. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work for you.

```
SELECT DATEPART(WEEK,[Date]),SUM([Dollar])
FROM [dbo].[TEST]
GROUP BY DATEPART(WEEK,[Date])
HAVING COUNT(DATEPART(WEEK,[Date])) >= 5
```

Here is a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4f6119/1).